# rails form partial breaks Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I"m trying to render a form_for partial in a bootstrap popover, and for some reason the form doesn't seem to be closing properly, breaking the popover.

_post_form.html.erb

```
test_text_1
<%= form_for(@reblog) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
test_text_2
```

the view helper calling the popover and form:

```
  def reblog_post(reblog)
    button_tag(class: "btn btn-xs", data: { toggle: "popover", placement: "bottom", html: true, content: (render partial: "shared/post_form") }) do
      '<a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></span></a>'.html_safe
    end
  end
```

The popover works just fine when there's only plain text or html, but as soon as I put the form_for in it, everything after the form_for (ie, test_text_2, as well as the form elements) renders outside of the popover, along with a trailing `">`, which makes it seem like the form fields aren't being closed properly.  Any plain text before the form (eg, test_text_1) still renders inside the form properly.  Am I missing a typo, or is there a specific way to render a form in a bootstrap popover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

`content: (render partial: "shared/post_form")`

Try:

`content: "#{ render partial: 'shared/post_form' }"`

You also want to make sure `popover` initialisation accept html content(default is text only) ie `$("#id").popover({html: 'true'})`

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options

Cheers